# Unable to proxy interface-implementing method | Unable to call Aerospike | Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot

Facing the mentioned issue and unable to connect to aerospike:

```
[2m2023-08-27 21:33:53.913[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m13487[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mo.s.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy         [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Unable to proxy interface-implementing method [public final com.aerospike.client.policy.Policy com.aerospike.client.AerospikeClient.getReadPolicyDefault()] because it is marked as final: Consider using interface-based JDK proxies instead!
[2m2023-08-27 21:33:53.913[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m13487[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mo.s.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy         [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Unable to proxy interface-implementing method [public final com.aerospike.client.policy.WritePolicy com.aerospike.client.AerospikeClient.getWritePolicyDefault()] because it is marked as final: Consider using interface-based JDK proxies instead!
[2m2023-08-27 21:33:53.918[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m13487[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mo.s.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy         [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Unable to proxy interface-implementing method [public final boolean com.aerospike.client.AerospikeClient.isConnected()] because it is marked as final: Consider using interface-based JDK proxies instead!
[2m2023-08-27 21:33:53.918[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m13487[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mo.s.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy         [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Unable to proxy interface-implementing method [public final void com.aerospike.client.AerospikeClient.prepend(com.aerospike.client.policy.WritePolicy,com.aerospike.client.Key,com.aerospike.client.Bin[]) throws com.aerospike.client.AerospikeException] because it is marked as final: Consider using interface-based JDK proxies instead!
[2m2023-08-27 21:33:53.918[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m13487[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mo.s.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy         [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Unable to proxy interface-implementing method [public final void com.aerospike.client.AerospikeClient.prepend(com.aerospike.client.async.EventLoop,com.aerospike.client.listener.WriteListener,com.aerospike.client.policy.WritePolicy,com.aerospike.client.Key,com.aerospike.client.Bin[]) throws com.aerospike.client.AerospikeException] because it is marked as final: Consider using interface-based JDK proxies instead!
[2m2023-08-27 21:33:53.918[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m13487[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mo.s.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy         [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Unable to proxy interface-implementing method [public final void com.aerospike.client.AerospikeClient.add(com.aerospike.client.async.EventLoop,com.aerospike.client.listener.WriteListener,com.aerospike.client.policy.WritePolicy,com.aerospike.client.Key,com.aerospike.client.Bin[]) throws com.aerospike.client.AerospikeException] because it is marked as final: Consider using interface-based JDK proxies instead!
[2m2023-08-27 21:33:53.918[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m13487[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mo.s.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy         [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Unable to proxy interface-implementing method [public final void com.aerospike.client.AerospikeClient.add(com.aerospike.client.policy.WritePolicy,com.aerospike.client.Key,com.aerospike.client.Bin[]) throws com.aerospike.client.AerospikeException] because it is marked as final: Consider using interface-based JDK proxies instead!
[2m2023-08-27 21:33:53.918[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m13487[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mo.s.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy         [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Unable to proxy interface-implementing method [public final void com.aerospike.client.AerospikeClient.get(com.aerospike.client.async.EventLoop,com.aerospike.client.listener.RecordListener,com.aerospike.client.policy.Policy,com.aerospike.client.Key) throws com.aerospike.client.AerospikeException] because it is marked as final: Consider using interface-based JDK proxies instead!
[2m2023-08-27 21:33:53.918[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m13487[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mo.s.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy         [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Unable to proxy interface-implementing method [public final com.aerospike.client.Record com.aerospike.client.AerospikeClient.get(com.aerospike.client.policy.Policy,com.aerospike.client.Key,java.lang.String[]) throws com.aerospike.client.AerospikeException] because it is marked as final: Consider using interface-based JDK proxies instead!
[2m2023-08-27 21:33:53.918[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m13487[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mo.s.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy         [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Unable to proxy interface-implementing method [public final void com.aerospike.client.AerospikeClient.get(com.aerospike.client.async.EventLoop,com.aerospike.client.listener.RecordListener,com.aerospike.client.policy.Policy,com.aerospike.client.Key,java.lang.String[]) throws com.aerospike.client.AerospikeException] because it is marked as final: Consider using interface-based JDK proxies instead!
[2m2023-08-27 21:33:53.918[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m13487[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mo.s.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy         [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Unable to proxy interface-implementing method [public final com.aerospike.client.Record com.aerospike.client.AerospikeClient.get(com.aerospike.client.policy.Policy,com.aerospike.client.Key) throws com.aerospike.client.AerospikeException] because it is marked as final: Consider using interface-based JDK proxies instead!
[2m2023-08-27 21:33:53.918[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m13487[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mo.s.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy         [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Unable to proxy interface-implementing method [public final com.aerospike.client.Record[] com.aerospike.client.AerospikeClient.get(com.aerospike.client.policy.BatchPolicy,com.aerospike.client.Key[],java.lang.String[]) throws com.aerospike.client.AerospikeException] because it is marked as final: Consider using interface-based JDK proxies instead!
[2m2023-08-27 21:33:53.918[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m13487[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mo.s.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy         [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Unable to proxy interface-implementing method [public final void com.aerospike.client.AerospikeClient.get(com.aerospike.client.policy.BatchPolicy,java.util.List) throws com.aerospike.client.AerospikeException] because it is marked as final: Consider using interface-based JDK proxies instead!
[2m2023-08-27 21:33:53.918[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m13487[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mo.s.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy         [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Unable to proxy interface-implementing method [public final void com.aerospike.client.AerospikeClient.get(com.aerospike.client.async.EventLoop,com.aerospike.client.listener.BatchListListener,com.aerospike.client.policy.BatchPolicy,java.util.List) throws com.aerospike.client.AerospikeException] because it is marked as final: Consider using interface-based JDK proxies instead!
[2m2023-08-27 21:33:53.918[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m13487[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mo.s.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy         [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Unable to proxy interface-implementing method [public final com.aerospike.client.Record[] com.aerospike.client.AerospikeClient.get(com.aerospike.client.policy.BatchPolicy,com.aerospike.client.Key[]) throws com.aerospike.client.AerospikeException] because it is marked as final: Consider using interface-based JDK proxies instead!
[2m2023-08-27 21:33:53.919[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m13487[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mo.s.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy         [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Unable to proxy interface-implementing method [public final void com.aerospike.client.AerospikeClient.get(com.aerospike.client.async.EventLoop,com.aerospike.client.listener.BatchSequenceListener,com.aerospike.client.policy.BatchPolicy,java.util.List) throws com.aerospike.client.AerospikeException] because it is marked as final: Consider using interface-based JDK proxies instead!
[2m2023-08-27 21:33:53.919[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m13487[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mo.s.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy         [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Unable to proxy interface-implementing method [public final void com.aerospike.client.AerospikeClient.get(com.aerospike.client.async.EventLoop,com.aerospike.client.listener.RecordSequenceListener,com.aerospike.client.policy.BatchPolicy,com.aerospike.client.Key[]) throws com.aerospike.client.AerospikeException] because it is marked as final: Consider using interface-based JDK proxies instead!
[2m2023-08-27 21:33:53.919[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m13487[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mo.s.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy         [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Unable to proxy interface-implementing method [public final void com.aerospike.client.AerospikeClient.get(com.aerospike.client.async.EventLoop,com.aerospike.client.listener.RecordArrayListener,com.aerospike.client.policy.BatchPolicy,com.aerospike.client.Key[]) throws com.aerospike.client.AerospikeException] because it is marked as final: Consider using interface-based JDK proxies instead!
[2m2023-08-27 21:33:53.919[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m13487[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mo.s.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy         [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Unable to proxy interface-implementing method [public final void com.aerospike.client.AerospikeClient.get(com.aerospike.client.async.EventLoop,com.aerospike.client.listener.RecordArrayListener,com.aerospike.client.policy.BatchPolicy,com.aerospike.client.Key[],java.lang.String[]) throws com.aerospike.client.AerospikeException] because it is marked as final: Consider using interface-based JDK proxies instead!
[2m2023-08-27 21:33:53.919[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m13487[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mo.s.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy         [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Unable to proxy interface-implementing method [public final void com.aerospike.client.AerospikeClient.get(com.aerospike.client.async.EventLoop,com.aerospike.client.listener.RecordSequenceListener,com.aerospike.client.policy.BatchPolicy,com.aerospike.client.Key[],java.lang.String[]) throws com.aerospike.client.AerospikeException] because it is marked as final: Consider using interface-based JDK proxies instead!
[2m2023-08-27 21:33:53.919[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m13487[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mo.s.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy         [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Unable to proxy interface-implementing method [public final void com.aerospike.client.AerospikeClient.put(com.aerospike.client.policy.WritePolicy,com.aerospike.client.Key,com.aerospike.client.Bin[]) throws com.aerospike.client.AerospikeException] because it is marked as final: Consider using interface-based JDK proxies instead!
[2m2023-08-27 21:33:53.919[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m13487[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mo.s.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy         [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Unable to proxy interface-implementing method [public final void com.aerospike.client.AerospikeClient.put(com.aerospike.client.async.EventLoop,com.aerospike.client.listener.WriteListener,com.aerospike.client.policy.WritePolicy,com.aerospike.client.Key,com.aerospike.client.Bin[]) throws com.aerospike.client.AerospikeException] because it is marked as final: Consider using interface-based JDK proxies instead!
[2m2023-08-27 21:33:53.919[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m13487[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mo.s.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy         [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Unable to proxy interface-implementing method [public final void com.aerospike.client.AerospikeClient.append(com.aerospike.client.policy.WritePolicy,com.aerospike.client.Key,com.aerospike.client.Bin[]) throws com.aerospike.client.AerospikeException] because it is marked as final: Consider using interface-based JDK proxies instead!
[2m2023-08-27 21:33:53.919[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m13487[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mo.s.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy         [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Unable to proxy interface-implementing method [public final void com.aerospike.client.AerospikeClient.append(com.aerospike.client.async.EventLoop,com.aerospike.client.listener.WriteListener,com.aerospike.client.policy.WritePolicy,com.aerospike.client.Key,com.aerospike.client.Bin[]) throws com.aerospike.client.AerospikeException] because it is marked as final: Consider using interface-based JDK proxies instead!
[2m2023-08-27 21:33:53.919[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m13487[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mo.s.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy         [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Unable to proxy interface-implementing method [public final com.aerospike.client.task.RegisterTask com.aerospike.client.AerospikeClient.register(com.aerospike.client.policy.Policy,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,com.aerospike.client.Language) throws com.aerospike.client.AerospikeException] because it is marked as final: Consider using interface-based JDK proxies instead!
[2m2023-08-27 21:33:53.919[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m13487[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mo.s.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy         [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Unable to proxy interface-implementing method [public final com.aerospike.client.task.RegisterTask com.aerospike.client.AerospikeClient.register(com.aerospike.client.policy.Policy,java.lang.ClassLoader,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,com.aerospike.client.Language) throws com.aerospike.client.AerospikeException] because it is marked as final: Consider using interface-based JDK proxies instead!
[2m2023-08-27 21:33:53.919[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m13487[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mo.s.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy         [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Unable to proxy interface-implementing method [public final java.lang.Object com.aerospike.client.AerospikeClient.execute(com.aerospike.client.policy.WritePolicy,com.aerospike.client.Key,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,com.aerospike.client.Value[]) throws com.aerospike.client.AerospikeException] because it is marked as final: Consider using interface-based JDK proxies instead!
[2m2023-08-27 21:33:53.919[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m13487[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mo.s.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy         [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Unable to proxy interface-implementing method [public final com.aerospike.client.task.ExecuteTask com.aerospike.client.AerospikeClient.execute(com.aerospike.client.policy.WritePolicy,com.aerospike.client.query.Statement,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,com.aerospike.client.Value[]) throws com.aerospike.client.AerospikeException] because it is marked as final: Consider using interface-based JDK proxies instead!
[2m2023-08-27 21:33:53.919[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m13487[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mo.s.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy         [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Unable to proxy interface-implementing method [public final com.aerospike.client.task.ExecuteTask com.aerospike.client.AerospikeClient.execute(com.aerospike.client.policy.WritePolicy,com.aerospike.client.query.Statement,com.aerospike.client.Operation[]) throws com.aerospike.client.AerospikeException] because it is marked as final: Consider using interface-based JDK proxies instead!
[2m2023-08-27 21:33:53.919[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m13487[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mo.s.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy         [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Unable to proxy interface-implementing method [public final void com.aerospike.client.AerospikeClient.execute(com.aerospike.client.async.EventLoop,com.aerospike.client.listener.ExecuteListener,com.aerospike.client.policy.WritePolicy,com.aerospike.client.Key,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,com.aerospike.client.Value[]) throws com.aerospike.client.AerospikeException] because it is marked as final: Consider using interface-based JDK proxies instead!
[2m2023-08-27 21:33:53.919[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m13487[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mo.s.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy         [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Unable to proxy interface-implementing method [public final void com.aerospike.client.AerospikeClient.delete(com.aerospike.client.async.EventLoop,com.aerospike.client.listener.DeleteListener,com.aerospike.client.policy.WritePolicy,com.aerospike.client.Key) throws com.aerospike.client.AerospikeException] because it is marked as final: Consider using interface-based JDK proxies instead!
[2m2023-08-27 21:33:53.919[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m13487[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mo.s.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy         [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Unable to proxy interface-implementing method [public final boolean com.aerospike.client.AerospikeClient.delete(com.aerospike.client.policy.WritePolicy,com.aerospike.client.Key) throws com.aerospike.client.AerospikeException] because it is marked as final: Consider using interface-based JDK proxies instead!
[2m2023-08-27 21:33:53.919[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m13487[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mo.s.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy         [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Unable to proxy interface-implementing method [public final boolean com.aerospike.client.AerospikeClient.exists(com.aerospike.client.policy.Policy,com.aerospike.client.Key) throws com.aerospike.client.AerospikeException] because it is marked as final: Consider using interface-based JDK proxies instead!
[2m2023-08-27 21:33:53.919[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m13487[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mo.s.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy         [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Unable to proxy interface-implementing method [public final void com.aerospike.client.AerospikeClient.exists(com.aerospike.client.async.EventLoop,com.aerospike.client.listener.ExistsListener,com.aerospike.client.policy.Policy,com.aerospike.client.Key) throws com.aerospike.client.AerospikeException] because it is marked as final: Consider using interface-based JDK proxies instead!
[2m2023-08-27 21:33:53.920[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m13487[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mo.s.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy         [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Unable to proxy interface-implementing method [public final boolean[] com.aerospike.client.AerospikeClient.exists(com.aerospike.client.policy.BatchPolicy,com.aerospike.client.Key[]) throws com.aerospike.client.AerospikeException] because it is marked as final: Consider using interface-based JDK proxies instead!
[2m2023-08-27 21:33:53.920[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m13487[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mo.s.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy         [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Unable to proxy interface-implementing method [public final void com.aerospike.client.AerospikeClient.exists(com.aerospike.client.async.EventLoop,com.aerospike.client.listener.ExistsArrayListener,com.aerospike.client.policy.BatchPolicy,com.aerospike.client.Key[]) throws com.aerospike.client.AerospikeException] because it is marked as final: Consider using interface-based JDK proxies instead!
[2m2023-08-27 21:33:53.920[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m13487[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mo.s.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy         [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Unable to proxy interface-implementing method [public final void com.aerospike.client.AerospikeClient.exists(com.aerospike.client.async.EventLoop,com.aerospike.client.listener.ExistsSequenceListener,com.aerospike.client.policy.BatchPolicy,com.aerospike.client.Key[]) throws com.aerospike.client.AerospikeException] because it is marked as final: Consider using interface-based JDK proxies instead!
[2m2023-08-27 21:33:53.920[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m13487[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mo.s.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy         [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Unable to proxy interface-implementing method [public final void com.aerospike.client.AerospikeClient.query(com.aerospike.client.async.EventLoop,com.aerospike.client.listener.RecordSequenceListener,com.aerospike.client.policy.QueryPolicy,com.aerospike.client.query.Statement) throws com.aerospike.client.AerospikeException] because it is marked as final: Consider using interface-based JDK proxies instead!
[2m2023-08-27 21:33:53.920[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m13487[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mo.s.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy         [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Unable to proxy interface-implementing method [public final com.aerospike.client.query.RecordSet com.aerospike.client.AerospikeClient.query(com.aerospike.client.policy.QueryPolicy,com.aerospike.client.query.Statement) throws com.aerospike.client.AerospikeException] because it is marked as final: Consider using interface-based JDK proxies instead!
[2m2023-08-27 21:33:53.920[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m13487[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mo.s.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy         [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Unable to proxy interface-implementing method [public final void com.aerospike.client.AerospikeClient.truncate(com.aerospike.client.policy.InfoPolicy,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.util.Calendar) throws com.aerospike.client.AerospikeException] because it is marked as final: Consider using interface-based JDK proxies instead!
[2m2023-08-27 21:33:53.920[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m13487[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mo.s.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy         [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Unable to proxy interface-implementing method [public final com.aerospike.client.cluster.Node com.aerospike.client.AerospikeClient.getNode(java.lang.String) throws com.aerospike.client.AerospikeException$InvalidNode] because it is marked as final: Consider using interface-based JDK proxies instead!
```

Im getting this warning msg while running the service and because of the same, not able to connect to aerospike.

Note: Getting this issue, when im creating a bean of 'AerospikeClient' with @RefreshScope as:

```
        @Bean
    @RefreshScope
    AerospikeClient aerospikeClient() {
        System.out.println("AerospikeBeanInit");
        List<Host> hostList = null;
        if(aerospikeHostList.contains(",")) {
            hostList = new ArrayList<>();
            String[] hostNames = aerospikeHostList.split(",");
            for(String hostName : hostNames) {
                Host host = new Host(hostName, aerospikePort);
                hostList.add(host);
            }
        }
        if(CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(hostList)) {
            Host[] hostArray = new Host[hostList.size()];
            return new AerospikeClient(clientPolicy, hostList.toArray(hostArray));
        }
        return new AerospikeClient(clientPolicy, aerospikeHostList, aerospikePort);
    }
```

**Help me resolve this issue as I want to use the annotation @RefreshScope on the same**

**Help me resolve this issue as I want to use the annotation @RefreshScope on the same**